# How to reduce blur or increase brightness on an image in angular

Tags: angular, npm

Is there in angular some libraries who can help me to reduce blur and/or increase brithgness on an image ?

Answer (score 1):

You have `blur()` and `brightness()` also in CSS. Is that not good?

[blur](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/blur()) [brightness](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/brightness())

Comment: If you use `[style.filter]="..."` with variables, you can make some like this:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hot2sl?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: I'm working with an upload file. So I want to reduce the blur on upload image. So I don't think I can use css

Answer (score 0):

You can look at some NPM modules like:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/image-brightness
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/image-filter-brightness
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-image-blur